# Custom Model Relationship (CMS Page + Product)

Tags: magento2, product, module, cms-pages, serialize

I am trying to assign a *Product Object* to a *CMS Page Object*, so when you have the *CMS Page Object*, you can do something like this:

```
$product = $page->getProduct();
```

I have modified the CMS Page Form to have an input field for the Product ID, which saves to the database. I have then created a Custom ReadHandler for the CMS Page to set the relationship like so:

```
public function execute($entity, $arguments = [])
{
    if ($entity->getId()) {
        $additionalData = $this->resourcePage->getAdditionalData((int)$entity->getId());

        if (!is_null($additionalData)) {
            $additionalData = json_decode($additionalData, true);
            $entity->setData('additional_data', $additionalData);

            if (isset($additionalData['product_id'])) {
                $product = $this->productRepository->getById($additionalData['product_id']);
                $entity->setData('product', $product);
            }
        }
    }
    return $entity;
}
```

This works on the frontend when the page loads I can see the *Product Object* is within the *CMS Page Object*, and I can do `$product = $page->getProduct();`

However, when I load the page in the backend (for editing) I get this error:

> Uncaught Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed in /vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:136
>
> Stack trace:
>
> 0 /vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(136):
>   session_write_close()
>
> 1 [internal function]:
>   Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->writeClose()
>
> 2 {main} thrown in
>   /vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php on line 136

I am aware I can't serialize a Closure, but I can't change the *Product Object* which is what contains the Closures, which is why I am here...

I am guessing some standard Magento Backend functionality is causing this, but I cannot figure out how to get around it.